# Dango : Andministration page do not diplay user new well

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am learning Django 2.2, I am trying to display the user name of my model named 'Profile' but instead I have : Profile objet(3), Profile Object(4)

Here is the code in Profile Apps=> models.py :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator

# Create your models here.

class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/img', validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['png'])], blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

@property
def get_created(self):
    return self.created.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")

def __str__(self):
    return "{}-{}".format(self.name, self.get_created)
```

Here is the code in Profile Apps=> admin.py :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Profile
# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Profile)
```

Here is the code in Profile Apps=> **init**.py :

```
default_app_config = "profiles.apps.ProfilesConfig"
```

I have this, instead of user name:
[image]

Comment: You need to add a `__str__` method to your `Profile` model

Comment: You added `__str__` to `Skill` model but in admin looking on `Profile` model.

Comment: I sorry I have eupdate the code